# Validity Small Sample Size

Tags: small-sample

A fellow working student of mine is doing her bachelor's thesis right now. 
She's looking into the effect that a brands presence in ski resorts has on customer perception of that brand.

Since she is only considering one ski resort and one brand, I am really doubting the validity of her approach. However, she has said that her supervisor told her to do so.

I think that that approach is wrong, but I would like to hear other voices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the approach is wrong or correct depends on the specific research question she wants to ask. If the question involve the effect of ANY brand on ANY resort, then it is wrong: with only one ski resort and one brand the conclusion of her study will be specific to the resort/brand analyzed (I would say it is a case study), and there is no reason to assume they will generalize to other brands/resorts.

Comment: She said that she wanted to see the effect on any ski resort in general (so explicitly no case study). Which is what confused me. 
Thanks for the answer. And sorry, I should have clarified that beforehand.